# Why does creating a droplet via Ansible fail complaining about "dopy" dependency?

Tags: ansible, digital-ocean

I'm trying to create a droplet on DigitalOcean using Ansible. I have written the following script for that

```
- name: launch DO droplet
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: spin up DO droplet
      local_action:
        module: digital_ocean
             state=present
             command=droplet
             name=test1
             api_token=***
             ssh_key_ids=DigitalOcean_MAC
             size_id=2gb
             region_id=ams2
             image_id=ubuntu-18-04-x64
             wait_timeout=500
      register: my_droplet
    - name: print info about my_droplet
      local_action:
        module:  debug
            msg="ID is {{ my_droplet.droplet.id }} IP is {{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }}"

    - name: Add new droplet to host group
      local_action: add_host hostname={{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }} groupname=launched

    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      local_action: wait_for host={{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }} port=22 delay=60 timeout=320 state=started
```

I'm executing it via

> ansible-playbook create_droplet.yml -c local -i localhosts

But I'm always getting the following error

```
> PLAY [launch DO droplet]
> ****************************************************************************************************************
> 
> TASK [spin up DO droplet]
> *************************************************************************************************************** fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg":
> "dopy >= 0.3.2 required for this module"}     to retry, use: --limit
> @/Users/wim/Dropbox/Programming/Ansible/DigitalOcean/create_droplet.retry
> 
> > PLAY RECAP
> > ****************************************************************************************************************************** localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0   
> > failed=1
```

I'm installing that dopy thing using:

> sudo pip install 'dopy>=0.3.5,<=0.3.5'

But also that does not help.

Any suggestions what's wrong...or is there another way to create a droplet on DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 2):

> sudo pip install 'dopy>=0.3.5,<=0.3.5'

Won't help without knowing what `ansible_python_interpreter` you are using, since `-c local` requires the local that ansible is using to contain the module, and not whatever random python you ran `pip` against. I have a strong suspicion ansible will default to `/usr/bin/python` which might be fine, but I'm guessing in your circumstance it's not otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question.

It is very likely you can achieve success via `ansible-playbook -e ansible_python_interpreter=$(which python) ...` since the `pip` from your `$PATH` is *probably* the same from the `python` on your path. You can, of course, be certain via `python -c "import dopy"` in that same terminal and ensure nothing explodes.